# URL mapping after logging in

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a login servlet with the URL mapping "/Login", which manages the user input and the login procedure. However, when the user logs in, the web site is directed to the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/pilot_1/Login
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/pilot_1/checklistallitem
```

It is to mention that the first URL works fine, it shows all the data, but I am not sure why the URL does not show up as desired. Here's my doPost method of the Login Servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = req.getParameter("j_username");
    String password = req.getParameter("j_password");

    if (users.containsKey(username)){
        if ( users.get(username).equals(password)){
            req.getSession().setAttribute("active_window", "Checklist");
            req.getSession().setAttribute("current_team", "allteams");

            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/checklistallteam").forward(req, resp);

        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid ID or Password");
        }
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid ID or Password");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing mixing Swing with Servlets?

Comment: Also, look into [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between a redirect and a forward. When you forward a request with a dispatcher the resolution and processing happens server side, then the final response is returned to the calling client. On the other hand, when you issue a redirect, there is an intermediate response to the client that basically tells it - 'Call this other URL to fulfill the request'. As a side effect the client will be aware of the URL of the new resource and will update the location bar to reflect it.

Because a forward is processed entirely on the server side the URL in the clients location bar does not change.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thanks. However, now I face an issue that I had tremendous confusion with. 
The desired URL to invoke the correct url is "localhost:8080/pilot_1/checklistallitem". 
However, when I use resp.sendRedirect("/checklistallteam"), I get forwarded to the URL "localhost:8080/checklistallitem", and when I use resp.sendRedirect("pilot_1/checklistallteam"), I get forwarded to the URL "localhost:8080/pilot_1/pilot_1/checklistallitem"

Comment: @naddnan - use the first form, without the leading forward slash.